# Passing an ARN from ConfigMap tp TargetGroupBinding in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I need to do a Target Group Binding in AWS.
I am creating almost all resources using Terraform (EKS cluster, nodes, other AWS services).
On top of it I am having a Kubernetes cluster of course and code written in K8s yamls.

I am creating a service like f.e. nginx proxy which is meant to be dong its proxying job.

What I want to achieve is to bind the proxy service

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy-service
  namespace: nginx-proxy
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-proxy
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
```

with a target group created in Terraform

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "nginx-proxy" {
  name        = "${var.environment}-proxy-tg"
  port        = 443
  protocol    = "HTTPS"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "ip"
}
```

There is a CRD TargetGroupBinding that I can use for this purpose, but I need to pass the TargetGroup ARN to it

```
apiVersion: elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: TargetGroupBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy-tgb
  namespace: nginx-proxy
spec:
  serviceRef:
    name: nginx-proxy-service
    port: 443
  targetGroupARN: $(TARGETGROUP_ARN)
```

Firstly I thought that I can use a ConfigMap, but that TargetGroupBinding doesn't understand ConfigMaps.
Then I thought that I can use Kustomize, but I cannot figure out how (if it is possible) to pass a value from a ConfigMap that contains that value,

```
$ kubectl describe configmap proxy-cm
Name:         proxy-cm
Namespace:    nginx-proxy
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
targetgroup_arn:
----
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:<somevaluehere>:targetgroup/beta-proxy-tg/<somevaluethere>

BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

to a Kustomize, and then Kustomize can use it and replace proper fields in my TargetGroupBinding.

Do you have any ideas how can I get marry those two things?
Seems pretty common pattern, but as a newbie in Terraform and K8s  I cannot figure it out.

Comment: So you need to create a CRD and apply it?

Comment: ...with an exported attribute from the target group? Are you asking about `templatefile`, `yamlencode`, or possibly the Kubernetes provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to use Terraform to create infrastructure obcjets (EKS clusters, nodes, Load Balancers, Target groups and so on).
I want to use kubernetes/Kustomize/Helm code to create K8s objects like deployments, services, statefulsets ad so on.
I've almost done that using Helm chart approach

Terraform object creation:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "nginx-proxy" {
  name        = "${var.environment}-proxy-tg"
  port        = 443
  protocol    = "HTTPS"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "ip"
}

resource "kubernetes_config_map" "proxy_configmap" {
  metadata {
    name      = "proxy-cm"
    namespace = "nginx-proxy"
  }
  data = {
    targetgroup_arn  = "${aws_lb_target_group.nginx-proxy.arn}"
    lb-name = "${aws_lb.eks_alb.name}"
  }
  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.nginx-proxy-namespace]
}
```

_helpers.tpl

```
{{- define "awsLBTargetGroupArn" -}}
{{- (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" "nginx-proxy" "proxy-cm").data.targetgroup_arn }}
{{- end -}}
```

Helm templates:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy-service
  namespace: nginx-proxy
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-proxy
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443

apiVersion: elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: TargetGroupBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy-tgb
  namespace: nginx-proxy
spec:
  serviceRef:
    name: nginx-proxy-service
    port: 443
  targetGroupARN: {{ include "awsLBTargetGroupArn" . }}
```

I can see that kubectl shows me that it is being binded

```
✗ kubectl describe TargetGroupBinding nginx-proxy-tgb
Name:         nginx-proxy-tgb
Namespace:    nginx-proxy
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: nginx-proxy
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: nginx-proxy
API Version:  elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1
Kind:         TargetGroupBinding
(...)



Ip Address Type:  ipv4
  Service Ref:
    Name:            nginx-proxy-service
    Port:            443
  Target Group ARN:  arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:<somenumbershere>:targetgroup/beta-proxy-tg/bba0b9519459370e
  Target Type:       ip
Status:
  Observed Generation:  1
Events:
  Type    Reason                  Age                From                Message
  ----    ------                  ----               ----                -------
  Normal  SuccessfullyReconciled  48m (x3 over 83m)  targetGroupBinding  Successfully reconciled
```

But I can't see the nodes being attached in fact (solved and described down the post.)

```
✗ aws elbv2 describe-target-health  --target-group-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:<somenumbershere>:targetgroup/beta-proxy-tg/bba0b9519459370e
----------------------
|DescribeTargetHealth|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: I know I could do that by using proper Ingress class

`resource "kubernetes_ingress_class_v1" "ingress_class_default" {
  depends_on = [helm_release.loadbalancer_controller]
  metadata {
    name = "aws-application-load-balancer-controller"
    annotations = {
      "ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class" = "true"
    }
  }
  spec {
    controller = "ingress.k8s.aws/alb"
  }
}`

But this way I am using Terraform, to create K8s object that will create AWS object that was meant to be created by Terraform itself- I do not like that complicated solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question, there is a need to apply a CRD to the cluster where one of the arguments should be populated by the value provided from another resource that gets created. For this purpose, the `hashicorp/kubernetes` provider can be used, namely its [`kubernetes_manifest` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest). Based on the question it could look like the following:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "nginx-proxy" {
  name        = "${var.environment}-proxy-tg"
  port        = 443
  protocol    = "HTTPS"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "ip"
}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "target_group_binding_crd" {
  manifest = {
    apiVersion = "elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1"
    kind       = "TargetGroupBinding"

    metadata = {
      name      = "nginx-proxy-tgb"
      namespace = "nginx-proxy"
    }

    spec = {
      serviceRef = {
        name = "nginx-proxy-service"
        port = 443
      }
      targetGroupARN = aws_lb_target_group.nginx-proxy.arn
    }
  }
}
```

Where the target group ARN would be passed to the `kubernetes_manifest` resource using implicit dependency, i.e., `targetGroupARN = aws_lb_target_group.nginx-proxy.arn`.

Comment: That would make a sense if not the fact, that I am creating infrastructure using Terraform. After that, I am deploying my application layer using Kubernetes. So I first have to have a deployment, to which I can create a service, and than I can bind that service to a target_group_binding_crd.

In other words, I cannot bind something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Well, you didn't specify how you want to achieve this, there are of course other ways. Do you need a YML file only? As a side note: all the other K8s resources can be created with terraform as well.

Comment: I know they can, but I need it to be kept simple and as close to the docs as possible. Terraform was developed to create infrastructure and I want to keep it that way.
A man can do lots of stuff, even to plow a field with it bare hands. But there are other tools that does it better, faster and more efficiently. I am trying to keep that philosophy in my business as well :)

Comment: I meant to say there are other ways of doing the same thing with terraform, it depends what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sure, I understand Marko. Just wanted to say that I want to keep it simple and use native technologies and techniques as much as I can.

Comment: And I can adjust the answer if you need to have e.g., a YAML file, I just need to know what those native tools are. :)

Answer (score 0):

the reason why I could not find that attachment in AWS, was the fact that pod was in a bad state. When I fixed that pod, service was able to connect to it and then all the binding went fine. So we can consider above as the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).